# Nonlinear reccurence relation: $a^{2}_{n} - 2a_{n-1} = 0, a_{0} = 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

How would one go about solving such recurrence relation? I tried writting it as $$a_{n} = \sqrt{2a_{n-1}}$$

and after inputing some numbers it is obvious that $$a_n = 2 $$

But is this correct?

Comment: Maybe you mean to say $a_n\to2$?

Comment: Prove by induction that $a_n=2$. Note that $a_n$ could be negative, which is a problem. You probably want to assume this isn't the case.

Comment: @user170231 No, he probably meant $a_n=2$... note $a_0$...

Comment: If $a_n=-2$ for some $n$, what is $a_{n+1}$?

Comment: $a_n=\sqrt{2a_{n-1}}\implies a_n=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{2\sqrt{2a_0}}}}}$ where there are $n$ iterated square roots. Since $a_0=2$ and $\sqrt{2a_0}$ is again $2$, it is obvious that $a_n=2~\forall~n\geq 0$.

Comment: The original "recurrence" admits two possible values for $a_n$, so the interpretation with taking a square root does introduce an assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f (x)=\sqrt {2x}$

the fixed points are $0$ and $2$.

> if $a_0=0$ then $\forall n  \,a_n=0$
>
> if $a_0=2$ then $\forall n  \;a_n =2$

if $a_0 <0$ the sequence is not defined.

suppose $a_0>0.$
then $\forall n \;\; a_n>0$.

$f'(x)=\frac {1}{\sqrt {2x}}>0$

$\implies f $ is increasing at $[0,+\infty) $

$\implies (a_n) $ is monotonic.

on the other hand

$f (x)-x=\sqrt {x}(\sqrt {2}-\sqrt {x}). $

> - first case :$0 <a_0 <2$

then by induction  $0 <a_n<2$  and
$a_{n+1}-a_n=f (a_n)-a_n>0$

increasing and bounded, the sequence goes to $2$.

> - second case for you.

Answer (score 2):

From

$$a_n^2=2a_{n-1}$$ you draw $$a_n=\pm\sqrt{2a_{n-1}}.$$ Obviously, the negative solution must be rejected as it causes the next iterates to be undefined. Also note that $a_0=0$ makes the sequence all zeroes.

Otherwise, take the logarithm and set $b:=\log a$. The recurrence is

$$b_n=\frac{b_{n-1}+\log2}2.$$

Then by induction,

$$b_n=2^{-k}b_{n-k}+(1-2^{-k})\log 2=2^{-n} b_0+(1-2^{-n})\log 2$$

and

$$a_n=2\left(\frac{a_0}2\right)^{(2^{-n})}.$$

For any $a_0>0$, the sequence quickly converges to $2\left(\dfrac{a_0}2\right)^0=2$.